# Зачем нужен спецификатор PRIVATE в C++

Tags: c++, классы

Зачем нужен спецификатор `private` в C++, если по умолчанию итак все функции и переменные являются закрытыми?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например, потому, что в *структуре* по умолчанию все функции и поля являются *открытыми*.

Кроме того, текстовый порядок полей [влияет на порядок их инициализации в конструкторе](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#ctor-initializer-order)! Поэтому просто так переставлять поля класса нельзя, это может изменить смысл программы.

Пример. Допустим, что мы хотим, чтобы поле `len` было открытым, а поле `data` — закрытым.

```
class MyString
{
  public:
    unsigned len;
  private:
    char* data;
  public:
    MyString(const char* s) :
         len(std::strlen(s)),
         data(new char[len + 1])
    {
        std::memcpy(data, s, len + 1);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Мы не можем переставить местами `len` и `data`, потому что инициализаторы в конструкторе выполняются в том порядке, в котором указаны поля, а не в том порядке, в котором они написаны в коде! А значит, без `private` не обойтись.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, конечно, можно сначала в классе описывать закрытые члены и закрытые функции, а только потом открытые... И никогда не пользоваться `struct`, если нужен хоть один закрытый член...

Но, откровенно говоря, насколько же это неудобно - при изменении доступа нужно *перемещать* член в классе, интерфейс нужно *всегда* показывать только после внутренностей класса...

Нет, пожалуй, все же удобство запоминания на одно ключевое слово меньше не в состоянии перевесить все преимущества, этим ключевым словом предоставляемые, нет? :)